# CSS Selector for all data rows in a specific column of an html table element

Tags: css, html-table

I would like to add a CSS class name "currency" to the header (th) of my table's column and have all the children data cells (td) in the column align to the right.

My best attempt is :

```
table th.currency td {
    text-align: right;
}
```

However this obviously does NOT work.  I tried to make it direct descendants ">" but that didn't work either.

I'd like to avoid adding the individual "currency" class name to ALL the td cells.  Anybody got a solution?

Comment: First thing to know is that the cells are not children of the table headers.

Comment: Understood.  But is there some way I can categorize all cells in a specific column?  I was hoping if my th was inside the <thead> this would work (obviously not the case).  After all if you specific a width on that th element it will apply to the entire column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$.each($('th.currency'),function(idx,val) {

    var table = $(this).parent().parent();
    var colNumber = $(this).parent("tr").children().index($(this));
    var rows = table.children("tr");
    rows.find("td:nth-child(" + (colNumber + 1) + ")").addClass("currency");

});
```

Working jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/8XSLF/

If the currency class doesn't right align, you can use the css function instead:

```
    rows.find("td:nth-child(" + (colNumber + 1) + ")").css("text-align","right");
```

This can be put in a script shared among many pages, but can't be done with just CSS alone.

Comment: This is what I was getting to.

Comment: @CalebDoucet Yep, I saw that..  Thanks for mentioning it, because that is what spurred me to put it together.  Upvotes for you!

Comment: thanks! I'm not the best with jquery so that would have taken me a while to do haha.

Comment: Thanks.  Given you the answer and @CalebDoucet an upvote.  Seems as though no nice simple CSS only solution is possible:(  But you came up with a clever solution to work across multiple file so you win!  Having said that I'm going with in-line styling so its more obvious whats happening in the code.

Answer (score 7):

If you know the column number you can use css selector of nth child on all trs in table.

```
table tr td:nth-child(n /*this is the column number*/)
{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YpAmY/)

Edit: You could also give the tables unique ids and target them that way:

```
#table1 tr td:nth-child(3 /*this is the column number*/)
{
    text-align: right;
}
#table2 tr td:nth-child(2 /*this is the column number*/)
{
    text-align: right;
}
#table3 tr td:nth-child(5 /*this is the column number*/)
{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: this is along the correct line.  However I want a style I can apply to many tables.  The column number will not always be the same.  So instead of assigning 'n' I would like to specify by a class name.

Comment: you could probably use jquery to find the th that has the class and then apply the class to all the td's in that table that are in the same column. Other than that the only other way I know would be to give the class to all the tds...

Comment: Since the same rule should apply to different tables "n" will be different in each case that won't work.  This rule is intended to be part of a CSS File shared across many views so it would need to be dynamic.  Don't believe you can or it makes sense to put JQuery in a CSS File??

Comment: Give the tables unique ids and make a class for each of them?

Comment: Hrm...  adding the unique ids is a pretty solid idea to keep it static CSS.

Answer (score -1):

add comma (,) between table, th, and td ( yours not apply to th and td